# Image won't show when loaded from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, arrays, android-imageview, sugarorm

In android im trying to save an image to an local sqlite databate with sugar ORM and then load it somewhere else.  but the image won't show and i keep getting:

```
image header:[5b 42 40 32 30 36 39 38], stream len = 12, read byte count = 8, valid byte count = 8, [[B@20698]

--- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

To save the image:

```
          byte[] image = Utilities.getBytes(pImage);
            Log.e("TAG", String.valueOf(image));
            Product product = new Product(pName, pBrand, pExpireDate, image);
            product.save();
```

To load:

```
        Log.e("TAG", String.valueOf(product1.image));
        Bitmap image = Utilities.getImage(product1.image);
        pImage.setImageBitmap(image);
```

Utilities class:

```
public class Utilities {
    public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }
    public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image)
    {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try `Utilities.getImage( Utilities.getBytes(img))` and see whether work well

Comment: Getbytes needs à bitmap not à byte array

Comment: I mean that use this line and see whether the output is a normal bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a bug in Sugar ORM when you add an dependency to gradle it takes the latest release and not the latest commit. when i included the latest Surgar ORM commit as a library project it was fixed.